# Nested loops in nested lists

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I am trying to build a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game in python, to check for a win I am using a nested loop to search for a match in a nested lists. For some reason my code will only search the first nested list and not the rest of them as I expected it to.

```
board = [ 'O', 'X', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X' ]
wins = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]

def checkWin(player):
    win = False
    for test in wins:
        print (test)
        count = 0
        for squares in test:
            if board[squares] == player:
                count = count + 1
            if count == 3:
                win = True
        return win

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("\nChecking board for X win ...\n")
    if checkWin("X"): 
        print ("Game over, X wins!")

    print ("\nChecking board for O win ...\n")
    if checkWin("O"):
        print ("Game over, O wins")
```

Based on the board provided a win for O is expected instead, this is the output I get:

```
Checking board for X win ...

[0, 1, 2]

Checking board for O win ...

[0, 1, 2]
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You return immediately, you need to indent your return value back.

Comment: You return after the first iteration over test,  dedent `return win` in line with your first `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return from the first nested list test, *regardless* of wether those three squares matched. Instead, only return if `win` is true:

```
def checkWin(player):
    win = False
    for test in wins:
        count = 0
        for squares in test:
            if board[squares] == player:
                count = count + 1
            if count == 3:
                win = True
        if win:
            return True
    return False
```

If `win` is false, the above continues to the next nested list for the next test.

Better still, just return when `count` is set to `3`, since you know you have found a match at that stage:

```
def checkWin(player):
    for test in wins:
        count = 0
        for squares in test:
            if board[squares] == player:
                count = count + 1
            if count == 3:
                return True
    return False
```

Instead of counting, you could use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def checkWin(player):
    for test in wins:
        if all(board[square] == player for square in test):
            return True
    return False
```

`all()` returns `False` early, as soon as one of the tests in the generator expression fails.

And the ultimate version adds [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to complete the test in one line:

```
def checkWin(player):
    return any(all(board[square] == player for square in test)
               for test in wins)
```

Demo:

```
>>> board = [ 'O', 'X', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'X', 'O', 'X', 'X' ]
>>> wins = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
>>> def checkWin(player):
...     return any(all(board[square] == player for square in test)
...                for test in wins)
... 
>>> checkWin('X')
False
>>> checkWin('O')
True
```